# Python AttributeError: 'Class' object has no attribute 'name' - SetUpClass

Tags: python, django, testing, model

I'm writing tests for a model in a Django app, but cannot get them to run. I've tried all I can think of to solve and searched but cannot find the solution.

The error I receive when I run the test is `AttributeError: 'UserModelTest' object has no attribute 'firstUser'`, which would suggest I haven't defined firstUser correctly.

Here are the relevant bits of code.

**tests.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import ContactForm
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class UserModelTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.firstUser = ContactForm(
            email="first@user.com",
            name="first",
            timestamp=datetime.today() + timedelta(days=2)
        )
        cls.firstUser.save()

    def test_contactform_str_returns_email(self):
        self.assertEqual("first@user.com", str(self.firstUser))
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class ContactForm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']
```

I'm using Python version 3.5 and Django version 1.10.

Comment: Why did you capitalize SetUpClass?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Also your problem is that you're assigning the user to the class itself, not any instance of the class.

Comment: (1) show the traceback (2) error message in body of question not same as in question header

Comment: @user2357112 my mistake, it should be `setUpClass`, thanks. Now fixed.

Comment: SOLVED: For Django 1.10 I should be using `setUpTestData` rather than `setUpClass`. `setUpClass` was used in a previous version of Django, which I had been using. I did not realise this had been deprecated. The Django docs cover the `setUpTestData` [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData). Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @James You should post that as an answer and accept it (in 2 days) so that others can find this information too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setUpClass` has been deprecated for Django (I believe since 1.8). In order to set up the class now, I needed to use `setUpTestData`. The remaining code still works. `setUpTestData` is then run only once before all test methods in the class (not once before each test).

i.e. the code should be:

```
class UserModelTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.firstUser = ContactForm(
            email="first@user.com",
            name="first",
            timestamp=datetime.today() + timedelta(days=2)
        )
        cls.firstUser.save()

    def test_contactform_str_returns_email(self):
        self.assertEqual("first@user.com", str(self.firstUser))
```

More information on setUpTestData can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData).